# Having Dependency on a thirdparty application in a Windows Application

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a windows application which lets say Depends on X third-party application which i have its installer file.

i wanna do this:

Deploy my application in a way that it would check if the application is installed other wise use the included installation file to install it,

How can i gain this using **Visual Studio Installer Project**?

Comment: What kind of installer are you using? E.g. in InstallShield you can define some prerequisites, they will do exactly what you want.

Comment: thanks @Feroc for replying, i wanna use the default Visual Studio Installer Project.

Comment: make use of the fileBrowserDialog and prompt the user to select the wanted program, if not the right program is selected/brows is cancelled, prompt for installing the program (my opinion about how to handle it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select prerequisites for the default installer, too:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165429(v=vs.80).aspx

That should do the trick.